# angular.js:12416 SyntaxError: Unexpected token D in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

I am working with **SpringBoot and AngularJS**

This is the Service of My Custom Directive
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, csvType, uploadUrl) {
        var fd = new FormData();

```
    fd.append('csvType', csvType);
    fd.append('file', file);
    console.log(csvType);
    console.log(fd);

    $http({
        url: uploadUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('Success: '+response.data);           
        return response.data;

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        var a=response.toString();
42:         console.log('a='+a);
        console.log('Error: '+response);
     });

}
```

Now in the Console I am getting the error :

new1.js:42 a=SyntaxError: Unexpected token D in JSON at position 0

Also I have cross-checked in the SpringBoot that it is returning a String only.

I want to return that String in my HTML.

Comment: which line is 42? please provide some more information on where the error is occurring

Comment: The passed JSON is not valid.

Comment: It is returning a String not a JSON

Comment: ?? But the error causing code (which you're actually not showing) expects to see JSON ... Aaand JSON is type of string.